# Asterisk 13.x and fail2ban regex string

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, fail2ban

After upgrading FreePBX, fail2ban does not work.  This is based on Asterisk version 13.19.1.

Asterisk-iptables is setup in fail2ban, but misses the login attempts.

Answer (score -1):

After many attempts at changing items, I was finally able to determine the issue was in the "failregex" located in "/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/asterisk.conf.

I was able to add the string below to the bottom of the list:

```
(?:NOTICE|SECURITY|WARNING).*(FailedACL|InvalidAccountID|ChallengeResponseFailed|InvalidPassword).*RemoteAddress=\"IPV4/UDP/<HOST>/.*
```

Other steps included:
- ensuring fail2ban was running as a service
- adding an entry for "asterisk-iptables" and pointing to the log files
- ensuring the asterisk logger was creating the log files.
I have not posted explanations on these items, as I was able to follow guides readily available on the internet.